# Installing pygame python games

Tags: python, pygame

I have a simple question. Lets say I have been making a game, and I wanted some of my friends to be able to download it online. Do they have to have `pygame` and `python` installed on there computer to download it?

The reason I asked this simple question is because I am thinking about releasing it for the general audience in future, and if they can't download due to not having `pygame`, I will not probably get much feedback or success.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend packaging or compiling your game to a standalone executable. Take a look at [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)

Or, take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency), there are many other methods for doing this.